# SQL Case statement with Parameter in it

Tags: sql, .net-3.5, windows-ce

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    B.StartDate,
    CASE
        WHEN B.startdate < getdate() THEN 1
        WHEN B.startdate > GETDATE() THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS Status,
    CASE
        WHEN BU.UserID = @UserID THEN 1 
        ELSE 2
    END AS Ownership
FROM 
    TblA AS B  
INNER JOIN 
    TblB AS BF ON B.ID = BF.Id
INNER JOIN 
    TblC AS BU ON B.ID = BU.ID     
WHERE 
    B.Deleted = 'False'
ORDER BY 
    Status, Ownership
```

I am trying to run the above query in SQL Server CE, where it is not allowing me to declare a variable in datatable (xsd). And as visible I cannot afford to write multiple queries because it's CE. So there any workaround, given my conditions?

`@UserID` - it keeps on saying that does not exists in parameter collection - where as I think that because I am using it in CASE thats why its complaining.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are getting a .NET error, but only show SQL. Please show how you set up the query (`sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@UserID"`, `sqlCommand.Parameters.Item("@UserID ").Value = userId;`, ...)

Comment: Not very sure if I got your question. But I am trying to create a Data-table in xsd and creating a fill method on it - to return rows.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help here for lack of experience. I hope others can.

Answer (score 0):

Case statement can use the variable for checking.

Not have much reputation to comment, just asking here 
can you provide more details for your requirements.

Have you declared the variable before this sql segment, if not just try to add the following :
declare @UserID integer= 1 and then execute the statement again.

Comment: Just added the actual error that comes up when I try to save it.

Comment: I am trying to do the above in SQL CE, where it is not allowing me to declare a variable in datatable(xsd)

Comment: if you are using this query from .net, then you can replace this variable from the code...

Comment: And if you cannot declare a variable in SQL CE, go for function or stored procedure and from there you can pass the value to you SQL case statement.

Comment: And if it works could you vote this answer 1 UP so that other users can also take benefit from this answer.